# UWP initializeCompontent Error

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I changed all the namespaces in my app. It was a grueling process. but now my app won't build because of this error. See the attached screenshot.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Silly question but easily missed sometimes - did you update the name-space in the app properties?  Re-factoring the name space does not always change it.

Comment: I updated it everywhere. I went through each file and did a find and replace. I updated it through the app properties and even project folder paths.

Comment: I got the app working again by creating a new project and copy and pasting all my code over into that new projects. What a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have missed something.  I just tried this on a new solution, and it worked fine, using Visual Studio 2015, Update 1.

**Create new UWP app (ILoveBurritos)**

[image: UWP App]

**Rename namespace using <kbd>F2</kbd> to ILoveTacos**

[image: Rename namespace]

**Resulting app still compiles and runs**

[image: ILoveTacos namespace]

Comment: Thanks Kory. I did it the most awkward way possible, lol. I did get the code working again by starting a new session and pasting my code in.

Comment: I remember hitting this error once, like you, and could not remember the final change that I missed to get things working again. Your approach to get your code working again is not entirely without merit.